# HAProxy with same request sometimes responding with NOSRV while backend is up

Tags: haproxy, 503-error

Im making the same request(POST /user/oauth) to haproxy but sometimes i get 503, sending requests directly to the backend always works

here is the logs:

1. local_server~ app/s2 0/0/0/100/100 200 813 - - --VN 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
   "POST /user/oauth HTTP/1.1"
2. local_server~ app/s1 0/0/1/107/108 200 820 - - --NI 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
   "POST /user/oauth HTTP/1.1"
3. local_server~ app/NOSRV 0/-1/-1/-1/0 503 216 - - SCNN 1/1/0/0/0
   0/0 "POST /user/oauth HTTP/1.1"
4. local_server~ app/NOSRV 0/-1/-1/-1/0 503 216 - - SCNN 1/1/0/0/0
   0/0 "POST /user/oauth HTTP/1.1"
5. local_server~ app/s2 0/0/1/106/107 200 831 - - --NI 2/2/0/0/0 0/0
   "POST /user/oauth HTTP/1.1"
6. local_server~ app/s1 0/0/1/3/6206 101 337 - - --NI 3/3/1/1/0 0/0
   "GET / HTTP/1.1"
7. local_server~ app/s1 0/0/1/83/84 200 258 - - --VN 2/2/0/0/0 0/0
   "POST /transaction/concludeTransaction HTTP/1.1"
8. local_server~ app/NOSRV 0/-1/-1/-1/0 503 216 - - SCNN 1/1/0/0/0
   0/0 "POST /user/oauth HTTP/1.1"
9. local_server~ app/s2 0/0/1/107/108 200 831 - - --NI 1/1/0/0/0 0/0
   "POST /user/oauth HTTP/1.1"

as you can see the POST /user/oauth sometimes go to s1 sometimes go to s2 and sometimes to NOSRV.

sometimes it pass 10 times in a row and sometimes it fails 10 times in a row.

here is my config:

```
defaults
log     global
mode    http
option  httplog
option  dontlognull
timeout connect 10000
timeout client  50000
timeout server  50000
retries 3
errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend local_server
bind *:8080 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxx/sslcert.pem
mode http
default_backend app

backend app
balance roundrobin
cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
http-send-name-header Host
server s1 172.26.13.134:3000 check cookie s1
server s2 172.26.13.134:3000 check cookie s2
http-request add-header X-Server %b
```

Edit:

i did redirect the request the a quick python server running on local host and still the problem persist.
so i did edit haproxy config file to have only server s1 127.0.0.1:8086 check cookie s1

and run the python script: python3 -m http.server 8086 --bind 127.0.0.1&

when i hit from postman i got like 3 succ on a row than a 503.

Comment: might be a good idea to add health check to your nodes https://www.haproxy.com/blog/how-to-enable-health-checks-in-haproxy/ ... you can compare those NOSERV timestamps to node down time and see if both nodes are down at a time when you're getting a NOSERV response

Comment: it is already there "check", also calling directly the node always works and the nodes are never down. when i make an api call from postman i get these random 503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is within the version, i read somewhere that version 1.9 work better than 2.*
i downloaded the source code and compiled with the following options
make TARGET=linux-glibc USE_PCRE2=1 USE_PCRE2_JIT=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_REGPARAM=1 USE_SYSTEMD=1 USE_THREAD=1

as you can see I omitted on purpose the lua5 option which is the only difference with the one you get from apt-get install.

the resulted binay work very well without any issue